What is and isn't copyrightable in a set of language flashcards?
In bookstores, one can buy decks of language flashcards that have been professionally curated, designed and released for purchase. As I understand it, it is fair use to port such a deck to an electronic form for one's own use.
Presume this deck has been ported in a way that does not utilize anything immediately copyrightable (graphic design elements, lengthy creative text, grammar explanations, etc.), but preserves the curated order, the words/basic phrases and their translations, and possibly example sentences. Would it be a copyright violation to distribute such a file widely without the permission of the original creators?
In my understanding, on one hand translations of words aren't copyrightable as basic facts, on the other the selection of words and their order might be constituting creative expression. And does the answer change if the flashcards are explicitly of, for example, "1000 most common English words" in that order?
I'm primarily interested in answers pertaining to EU and the US, but not limited to those.

What you are proposing is likely copyright violation
The selection of the words and the order in which they are presented are definitely literary works protected by copyright, just like an anthology of 17th-century poetry or a dictionary.
Even if they were the "1000 most common English words", I'm not sure that that is a fact - what those 1,000 words are will depend on how the author chose to define and search for that 1,000 and different authors would invariably have different lists. To take a very simple example, the top 1,000 words in spoken English will almost certainly be different from the top 1,000 in written English, and that's before we consider regional variations in English - a language with 450 million native speakers and up to 2 billion ESL speakers is going to have a lot of variation.

If you simply scan an automated corpus, like Google Books or Project Gutenberg, with no curation, the "1000 most common words" would probably not be protected.

@Barmar they would be different depending on which books you scan

@Trish "with no curation". You're just scanning whatever books happen to be in the corpus, not applying any creative decision making.

@Barmar The contents of the corpus are deciding what shows up. It is different from different countries.

The "1000 most common English words" perhaps wasn't a good example - the ask was about a selection that is based on objective criteria derived from facts, so for example "all known Charles Baudelaire poems, alphabetically". My very layman reading of Feist v. RTS is that in the US this wouldn't be copyrightable even if you were caught on video rewriting the original anthology word for word, while in the EU this might not be a copyright violation but could fall under database laws.

@Trish There has to be human creative decision making to confer copyright. Although some countries also allow copyright for "sweat of the brow".
